# TypeError listOfNames.split is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am very new to coding and javascript and working on a project at school. I am not into the answers as it does me know good to be given them.  however, I am stuck at a part of my program and I am unable to go any further in my testing.  wondered if someone could share a little insight as to why I would be getting typeError is not a function on the listOfNames.split(" "); area of my code as provided to me by the console.  It is very frustrating that I cant seem to figure our why.  Thank you in advance.  Here is what I have so far.

```
     var realNinjas = [
       'Chuck Norris',
       'Jackie Chan',
       'Lucy Liu',
       'Billy Blanks',
       'Michelle Yeoh',
    ]
    var createListOfObjects = function(listOfNames){
    var nameList = listOfNames.split(" ");
    var namesArr = [];
    // var firstName = [];
    // var lastname = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++){
           namesArr.push("firstName:" + nameList[0], " " + "lastName:" +            nameList[1]);

   }
         return;
   //OUTPUT: List of strings
}
var ninjaListOfObjects = createListOfObjects(realNinjas);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**`split`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is a method of type `String`, not of `Array`

Use `split` over each string in array within `loop`

```js
 var realNinjas = [
   'Chuck Norris',
   'Jackie Chan',
   'Lucy Liu',
   'Billy Blanks',
   'Michelle Yeoh',
 ]
 var createListOfObjects = function(listOfNames) {
   var namesArr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < listOfNames.length; i++) {
     var split = listOfNames[i].split(' ');
     namesArr.push("firstName:" + split[0], " " + "lastName:" + split[1]);
   }
   return namesArr;
 }
 var ninjaListOfObjects = createListOfObjects(realNinjas);
 console.log(ninjaListOfObjects);
```